# How extract group information from Excel file

Tags: excel, filter, grouping, copy-paste

Good morning in my timezone.

I received an Excel file with a lot of rows and columns.
When i use a filter in each column i am able to see all the values the column has when i pick each drop down button.

Question :

- How can i select and copy all the values of each filter?

Something very similar to group by in SQL.

Thanks in advance
Best regards

Comment: If you do a search for extracting unique values from a list in Excel, you'll find several methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I marked this question as Off-Topic, because I think it belongs to superuser and there you find your solution: [How do I get the distinct unique values in excel](https://superuser.com/questions/49614/how-do-i-get-the-distinct-unique-values-in-a-column-in-excel)

I wrote this as answer, because the answer does not exist on SO (but on superuser).